# SQL Server select for update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, locking

I am struggling to find a SQL Server replacement for `select for update` that works.

I have a master table that contains a column which is used for next order number. The application does a select from update on this row, reads the current value (while locked) adds one to this value and then updates the row, then uses the number it received. This process works perfectly on all databases I've tried but for SQL Server which does not seem to have any process for selecting data for exclusive use.

How do I do a locked read and update of something like a next order number from a sequence table is SQL Server?

BTW, I know I can use things like `IDENTITY` cols and stuff, to do this, but in this case I must read from this existing column. Get the value and inc it, and do it in a safe locked manner to avoid 2 users getting the same value.

UPDATE::

Thank you, that works for this case :)

```
DECLARE @Output char(30)

UPDATE scheme.sysdirm
SET @Output = key_value = cast(key_value as int)+1
WHERE system_key='OPLASTORD' 

SELECT @Output
```

I have one other place I do something similar. I read and lock a stock record too.

```
SELECT STOCK 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE.
```

I then do some validation and the do

```
UPDATE PRODUCT SET STOCK = ?
WHERE ID=?
```

I can't just use your above method here, as the value I update is based on things I do from the stock I read. But I need to ensure no one else can mess with the stock while I do this. Again, easy on other DB's with `SELECT FOR UPDATE`... is there a SQL Server workaround?? :)

Comment: Can you post the existing code ? I might be wrong but you might just want to do this : `UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple do an `UPDATE` that also reads out the new value into a SQL Server variable:

```
DECLARE @Output INT

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET @Output = YourColumn = YourColumn + 1
WHERE ID = ????

SELECT @Output
```

Since it's an atomic `UPDATE` statement, it's safe against concurrency issues (since only one connection can get an update locks at any one given time). A potential second session that wants to get the incremented value at the same time will have to wait until the first one completes, thus getting the next value from the table.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works great in that example. I have a little more tricky one (edited original post) which is again easy with SELECT FOR UPDATE, but not so sure your solutions works for that?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the `OUTPUT` clause of the `UPDATE` statement, although this will insert into a table variable.

```
Create table YourTable
(
    ID int,
    YourColumn int
)

GO

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, 1)
GO


DECLARE @Output TABLE
( 
    YourColumn int 
)

UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn =  YourColumn + 1
OUTPUT inserted.YourColumn  INTO @Output
WHERE ID = 1

SELECT TOP 1 YourColumn
FROM @Output
```

**** EDIT
If you want to ensure that no-one can change the data after you have read it, you can use a repeatable read. You should be aware that any reads of any tables you do will be locked for Update (pessimistic locking) and may cause Deadlocking. You can also sue the `SELECT ... FROM TABLE (UPDLOCK)` hint within a transaction.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT STOCK 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE ID = ?


.....
...

UPDATE Product
SET Stock = nnn
WHERE ID = ?

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```